# How do I Get and Set the SpeedDuplex values from the registry using C#?

Tags: c#

//Getting the Speed Duplex Value

```
string str = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0007","*SpeedDuplex", null);

lblRegistry.Text = str;
```

It was easy to get the value from the registry but to set the value there are errors like UnaouthoriseAccess or Incorrect parameter... 
Could you please tell me how to go through this...????

Comment: What errors? Show the exception information

Comment: If you get Unauthorized access, then you don't have access to the registry. You need administrative rights to write in that spot. Are you running the program with administrative rights? If not, then that is the solution.